# corrupt png when drawing a long canvass?

Tags: reactjs

I have a long pdf around to 6 pages that I am generation from html, and I am getting the corrupt png image error any idea how to solve this ? it happens only on ios safari

```js
html2canvas(
      document.getElementById('pdfItems')!,
      {
        onclone: function (clonedDoc) {
          // none ! hidden show !!
          clonedDoc.getElementById('pdfItems')!.style.display = 'flex';
        },
        //   // TO INCREASE QUALITY !!!!!!!!!!
        scale: /*3*/ 2,
      }
    ).then((canvas) => {
      //document.body.appendChild(canvas); // if you want see your screenshot in body.
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      
      //A4
      var imgWidth = 210;
      // PAGE height in px !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      var pageHeight = 295;
      // ???????? 2500 * 210 / 1140
      var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

      // ????????
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;
      // A4
      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);

      var topPadding = 10; // give some top padding to first page

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, topPadding, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      // is the image bigger than the page ??? image hight is bigger than pdf page !!
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        topPadding = heightLeft - imgHeight; // Starting position to continue from
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, topPadding, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
      doc.save(`${fileName()}.pdf`);
      setTimeout(() => _backdropContext.SetBackDrop(false), 500);
    });
  };
```

Comment: too big means bad I can get from your post

Comment: would you recommend pdf server rendering instead of web page ? or will I face the same issue up there ?